# Using same getopts arguments for different options

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopts

I created a bash script and i need help with getopts

Each options have arguments :

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:" opt
do
case $opt in
  a)  echo "$OPTARG";;
  b)  echo "$OPTARG";;
  c)  echo "$OPTARG";;
  /?) echo "wrong option $OPTARG";;
esac
done
```

If i want to use the same argument, i need to type -option arg for each options

```
./script.sh -a hello -b hello -c hello

hello
hello
hello
```

I would like to be able to use the script like a command, typing options all together when i have the same argument :

```
./script.sh -abc hello
```

Unfortunately bc is now the argument :

```
bc
```

Does anyone could help me please ?

Regards,

Comment: The `getopts` system doesn't allow that.  If an option needs an argument, then it should be specified independently.